# MATLAB r2013a on Mac OS 10.8.3 crashes when viewing documentation

Tags: matlab

(Running MATLAB 8.1.0.604 (R2013a), Mac OS 10.8.3)

When I use the `doc` command, for example, `doc fwrite;`, or when I click the "more help" item in the popup help bubble for a command, the documentation window opens, but MATLAB subsequently hangs (the spinning beachball appears). This lasts indefinitely, and I inevitably have to force quit MATLAB. This also happens when using the Publish option from the editor.

Anyone have any ideas for diagnosing this? I tried taking a process sample but I didn't see any info I could interpret, I think since it's in Java the relevant information is obfuscated behind the JVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this post on MatlabCentral: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71718 ... and more specifically this [bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/870843) which includes a "workaround." They don't suggest what could be the cause, but you might make sure that OS X is updated and that you have the [latest version of Java](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5648). If you do other work with Java or with WebKit these might cause issues.

Comment: Thanks. I have the latest official Java update, no special WebKit builds, latest OS and Safari versions. The fix worked though. The text is badly pixelated though, any idea how to make the text clearer? (I'm on a Retina MBP and the alternate browser in MATLAB renders at non-Retina resolution and with bad antialiasing).

Comment: I have a Retina MacBook Pro too, but I'm on R2012b and don't have this issue. The best you can do is file a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) with The MathWorks to let them know about this. It would be nice if their alternative browser was at least a modern one.

Comment: Thank you both! I do (unfortunately) not have a Retina MacBook, and on my Cinema Display the text (fortunately) looks fine. Matlab should really fix this, though.

Comment: No, they NEED to fix this! Turns out the workaround doesn't work for me. Or rather: it introduces a new bug. As soon as I open the doc browser the menu bar disappears. Does anybody else have this issue?

Comment: @Nagel: I feel your pain. But I don't have R2013a to test. After you confirm that you've applied the workaround correctly (and restarted Matlab and maybe OS X too) I can only think that you could try [filing a bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) describing the additional issue. They may get back to you with other workarounds. But I wouldn't expect this to be fixed until R2013b (they have no concept of software updates).

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have already solved the problem. Otherwise a solution has been found, the bug resides in the Access for Assistive devices (only for version 2012b and later). If you can turn them all off from System Preferences, do that. If you can't, type this in the command window:
com.mathworks.mlwidgets.html.HtmlComponentFactory.setBrowserProperty('JxBrowser.BrowserType','Mozilla15');

From http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/870843

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Matlab R2014a on OS 10.10.4. For me the solution involved disabling *Cinch* (a window management tool I had installed). This can be done by clicking on the Cinch icon in the menu bar then *Disable Cinch*, or from *System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Accessibility* (as MarcoB detailed in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

More suitable as comments (but I don't have enough rep yet):

I just updated to Java 1.8.0_73 and to Safari 9.1 and the patch horchler posted no longer works.

MarcoB's command still works for fixing the crashes. But with this, no longer retina resolution in the Doc browser (so it looks ugly).